# Grails with custom many to many relationship, relational table with parameters

Tags: grails, spring-security, many-to-many

I have domains: Comments, Secuser and Rating.

I would like that each comment can be rated once by SecUser +1 or -1. In the view of related comments (to the domain discussion) I would like to have a button to up-vote or down-vote the comment and refresh the view.
The code I have so far:
The comments view:

```
<tbody>
    <g:each in="${comments}" var="comm">
        <tr>
            <td>${comm.comment}</td>
            <td>${comm.commentBy}</td>
            <td><g:formatDate format="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" date="${comm.createDate}"/> </td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onclick="${remoteFunction(action: 'ratePositiveComment', update: 'content', params:[commentID:"${comm.id}"])}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="false" style="float:right">${comm.numberPositiveRatings}</span></button>
                &nbsp;
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onclick="${remoteFunction(action: 'rateNegativeComment', update: 'content', params:[commentID:"${comm.id}"])}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="false" onclick="addRating(-1, ${comm.id})" style="float:right">${comm.numberNegativeRatings}</span></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </g:each>
</tbody>
```

The comments controller:

```
class Comments {
    static belongsTo = Discussion
    Discussion discussion
    SecUser commentBy
    String comment
    Date createDate = new Date()
    static hasMany = [commRatings : Rating]

    public long getNumberPositiveRatings() {
    return  Rating.countByCommentRatedAndRate(this, 1);
    }

    public long getNumberNegativeRatings() {
        return  Rating.countByCommentRatedAndRate(this, -1);
    }

    List raters() {
        return commRatings.collect{it.ratingUser}
    }

    List addToPosRatingUser(SecUser user) {
        Rating.positiveRating(user, this)
        //return raters()
    }

    List addToNegRatingUser(SecUser user) {
        Rating.negativeRating(user, this)
       // return raters()
    }
```

Rating domain:

```
class Rating {
    static belongsTo = Comments
    int rate
    SecUser ratingUser
    Comments commentRated

    static Rating positiveRating(ratingUser, commentRated) {
        def m = Rating.findByRatingUserAndCommentRated(ratingUser, commentRated)
        if (!m) {
            m = new Rating()
            ratingUser?.addToRating(m)
            commentRated?.addToRating(m)
            m.rate = 1;
            m.save()
        }
        return m
    }

    static Rating negativeRating(ratingUser, commentRated) {
        def m = Rating.findByRatingUserAndCommentRated(ratingUser, commentRated)
        if (!m) {
            m = new Rating()
            ratingUser?.addToRating(m)
            commentRated?.addToRating(m)
            m.rate = -1;
            m.save()
        }
        return m
    }
}
```

In the domain SecUser (Spring security plugin) I added:

```
class SecUser {

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    String userEmail
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    static hasMany = [ratings:Rating]

    List ratedComments() {
        return ratings.collect{it.commentRated}
    }

    List addPosCommentRating(Comments comm) {
        Rating.positiveRating(this, comm)
        return ratedComments()
    }

    List addNegCommentRating(Comments comm) {
        Rating.negativeRating(this, comm)
        return ratedComments()
    }
```

The CommentsController was scaffolded, the only added functions are:

```
def ratePositiveComment() {
    def rater = SecUser.findById(springSecurityService.currentUser.id);
    if(rater!=null) {
        Comments comm = Comments.get(params.commentID);
        comm.addToPosRatingUser(rater);
        comm.save();
    }
}


def rateNegativeComment() {
    def rater = SecUser.findById(springSecurityService.currentUser.id);
    if(rater!=null) {
        Comments comm = Comments.get(params.commentID);
        comm.addToNegRatingUser(rater);
        comm.save();
    }
}
```

Error code that I am getting is:

```
No signature of method: ForumProject.SecUser.addToRating() is applicable for argument types: (ForumProject.Rating) values: [ForumProject.Rating : (unsaved)]
Possible solutions: addToRatings(java.lang.Object). Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: ForumProject.SecUser.addToRating() is applicable for argument types: (ForumProject.Rating) values: [ForumProject.Rating : (unsaved)]
Possible solutions: addToRatings(java.lang.Object)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `addTo` (and `removeFrom`) methods are derived from the name in the `hasMany` map. If you had declared

```
static hasMany = [rating:Rating]
```

then the `addTo` method would be `addToRating` and your code would be correct. As it is now you just need to change the calls to `addToRatings`.

p.s. This is bad:

```
def rater = SecUser.findById(springSecurityService.currentUser.id);
```

`springSecurityService.currentUser` is already what you want, the `SecUser` that was used to create the `Authentication` when logging in, and it's retrieved from the database via a query, not from some cache. But you discard it after getting its `id` so you can load it again using an inefficient dynamic finder. Always use `get` instead of `findById`. So your code there should just be

```
def rater = springSecurityService.currentUser
```

Comment: Thank you Burt for your fast reply. 
Unfortunatelly I cannot verify if it is the right answer as def rater = springSecurityService.currentUser is null even after login (default login screen provided with spring-security-core).... Any suggestions what might be wrong? Anyway, what you wrote gives sense.

Comment: That was unrelated to the question, just an extra note at the end.

Comment: Well it took couple of rebuilds and cleans, and now it is working. Thank you very much for your help Burt.